# Touchpad not seen, on an Asus ZenBook UX305c

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus

For some reason the touchpad on my new Asus ZenBook UX305 works perfectly under Windows 10, but under Ubuntu is not being recognized. It's like it's not even there.

Under standard Ubuntu (15.04 or 15.10 desktop AMD64) the mouse pointer doesn't even appear. Under lubuntu 15.10 the mouse pointer appears centerscreen, but doesn't move.

If I plug in an external USB mouse it works great, but that's not really an acceptable long term solution.

I checked under Software & Updates - 'Additional Drivers', but it only shows "Unknown: Unknown. This device is not working.", and I get the radio-button choice to "Usuing Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)" or "Do not use this device." Selecting the former doesn't seem to do anything.

At this point I'm not even sure how to figure out what I need to know to move forward. Any clues would be greatly appreciated.

cat /proc/bus/input/devices yields:

```
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=LNXPWRBN/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab41
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0006 Version=0000
N: Name="Video Bus"
P: Phys=LNXVIDEO/video/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=3e000b00000000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Asus WMI hotkeys"
P: Phys=asus-nb-wmi/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/asus-nb-wmi/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=80000 0 800000000000 0 0 a1606f00900000 8200027800501000 e000000000000 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=064e Product=9700 Version=0101
N: Name="USB2.0 UVC HD Webcam"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event7 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this will be fixed in the 4.4 kernel which will be available on January on its stable version or you can try the [4.4-rc5](https://www.kernel.org) right now.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, and kernel 4.4-rc6 (the latest I could find) didn't work for me. But getting the latest kernel sources and making a small hack did work:

https://florisvanvugt.wordpress.com/2015/12/26/making-asus-ux305ca-touchpad-work-in-ubuntu/

(Credit for this solution goes to Kevin Fenzi).
Hope this helps.